# How to convert a pandas Series of lists or tuples to a Series of numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a csv file with x, y, and z columns that represent coordinates in a 3-dimensional space. I need to create a distance matrix from each item over all other items.

I can easily read the csv with pandas read_csv function, resulting in a DataFrame like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

samples = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['source', 'name', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
    data = [['a', 'apple', 1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
            ['b', 'pear', 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
            ['c', 'tomato', 9.0, 8.0, 7.0],
            ['d', 'sandwich', 6.0, 5.0, 4.0]]
)
```

I can then convert the separate x, y, z columns into a Series of tuples:

```
samples['coord'] = samples.apply(
    lambda row: (row['x'], row['y'], row['z']),
    axis=1
)
```

or a Series of lists:

```
samples['coord'] = samples.apply(
    lambda row: [row['x'], row['y'], row['z']],
    axis=1
)
```

But I cannot create a Series of arrays:

```
samples['coord'] = samples.apply(
    lambda row: np.array([row['x'], row['y'], row['z']]),
    axis=1
)
```

I get the ValueError, "Shape of passed values is (4,3), indices imply (4,6)"

I'd really like to have the data prepped so that I can simply call the scipy's distance_matrix function, which expects two arrays, as follows:

```
dmat = scipy.spatial.distance_matrix(
    samples['coord'].values,
    samples['coord'].values
)
```

I am, of course, open to any more pythonic or more efficient way to achieve this goal if my approach is poor.

Comment: have you tried `v = df.values`, then just slice your `numpy` array anyway you like, e.g. `v[1, :]` or `v[:, 1]`?

Comment: @jp_data_analysis That's a similar approach to the self-answer I just posted, extracting the relevant data rather than keeping it in the dataframe. Good thought, and relieves me of my 'array vs matrix' mental block, thinking all members had to be the same type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This stores NumPy array in `coords`:

```
samples['coord'] = list(samples[['x', 'y', 'z']].values)
```

Now:

```
>>> samples.coord[0]
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.])
```

Comment: This clearly stores arrays, and even works in a more complex context, too. Passing samples.coord or samples.coord.values or np.asarray(samples.coord) to distance_matrix still results in the same error because it's shaped as (n,) rather than (n,3). Perhaps that's another question, or my approach was wrong-headed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I can just extract a numpy array from the dataframe and use it to get the distance matrix.

```
sample_array = np.array(samples[['x', 'y', 'z']])
dmat = scipy.spatial.distance_matrix(sample_array, sample_array)
```

But I'd still like to have those little arrays embedded in the dataframe, alongside the other data, and I'd upvote and accept an answer that can do that.